# Show folder a file is contained in with finder list view in OSX 10.8.4

Tags: macos, finder, folders, search

I am trying to consolidate files that may be spread around my mac (photos in this case).  I can tell the finder to search for images, but I am very used to in Windows where I can search for the file type across the computer, and then show a column in the details view that shows the path where the file is located.  So far, I cannot find such a thing in the list or coverflow view in the finder.

I know i can see it in the properties of the files, but it would be very helpful to see it at a glance for multiple files, instead of individually.  But since I can't sort by their folder location, I can't even assume that the file after it in the list is in the same folder, so I can't even infer where they are based on pictures around it.

Is there a way to show the path where a file is in a finder search?  Or lest that, perhaps something that could print out where the files are into a text document to help the search?

Answer (score 1):

Download [Alfred 2](http://www.alfredapp.com/). It is an excellent application that allows for a streamlined search of your computer's files, and it also allows has other uses such as opening other applications or webpages. It shows you the location of the file that you're accessing, so for example if you type "chrome" it will show the option of opening Chrome in its application location.

A useful shortcut is "apple click" which then opens up the location of the file.